# I keep getting a String out of bounds error, can someone help fix my code?

Tags: java, string, methods, char, return

The error is String index out of range: 0. I honestly don't even know if what I'm doing is right in the first place.

I have to create an entireName method and an initial method. Their names speak for themselves, pretty much entireName prints out the name depending on what the user gives me. If they only gave me a first and last name then that is all I would return.

Initials is the same bit. It takes the first letter from the name input and only returns the initials. like John Lee Smith would be J.L.S.

Can anyone help me to understand what is wrong? If you can't tell I'm only a beginner.

I have a tester program that returns the error 
java.lang.StringIndexoutofboundexception: String index out of Range: 0 
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658) 
at PersonName.Initials(PersonName.java:131) atTestPersonName2.testOneName(TestPersonName2.java:50)

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class PersonName
{

   private int numberOfNames ;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String suffixName;


        PersonName(){
        firstName=""; 
        middleName=""; 
        lastName=""; 
        suffixName=""; 
        numberOfNames=0;

    }
    public String getFirstName(){

        return firstName;
    }
    public String getMiddleName(){
        return middleName;
    }
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }
    public String getSuffixName(){
        return suffixName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String f){
        if((f.length() == 0) && (firstName.length() == 0)){
          numberOfNames = numberOfNames;   
        }else if(( f.length() > 0) && (firstName.length() == 0)){
            numberOfNames++;
        }
        firstName = f;
    }
    public void setMiddleName(String m){
         if((m.length() == 0) && (middleName.length() == 0)){
          numberOfNames = numberOfNames;   
        }else if(( m.length() > 0) && (middleName.length() == 0)){
            numberOfNames++;
        }
        middleName = m;
    }
    public void setLastName(String l){
         if((l.length() == 0) && (lastName.length() == 0)){
          numberOfNames = numberOfNames;   
        }else if(( l.length() > 0) && (lastName.length() == 0)){
            numberOfNames++;
        }
        lastName = l;
    }
    public void setSuffixName(String s){
        if((s.length() == 0) && (suffixName.length() == 0)){
          numberOfNames = numberOfNames;   
        }else if(( s.length() > 0) && (suffixName.length() == 0)){
            numberOfNames++;
        }
        suffixName = s;
    }
    public int getNumberOfNames(){

        return numberOfNames;
    }
        PersonName(String wholename)
    {   firstName=""; middleName=""; lastName=""; suffixName=""; numberOfNames=0;

        // store the name passed in to the method
       final int MAXNAMES = 4;
        String [] words = new String [MAXNAMES];
        String testname=wholename;
         // initialize number of names found
        int numnames=0;
         // on each iteration remove one name
       StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(wholename);
       while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
         words[numnames++]=st.nextToken();
     }

     if (numnames ==1)
      {  setFirstName(words[0]);}
     else if (numnames == 2)
      {  setFirstName(words[0]);
        setLastName(words[1]);
      }
     else if (numnames == 3)
      {  setFirstName(words[0]);
        setMiddleName(words[1]);
        setLastName(words[2]);
      }
     else if (numnames == 4)
      {  setFirstName(words[0]);
        setMiddleName(words[1]);
        setLastName(words[2]);
        setSuffixName(words[3]);

      }

    }
    public String EntireName(){
         String EntireName = " ";
        //String EntireName = getFirstName() + " " + getMiddleName() + " " + getLastName() + " " + getSuffixName();
        if(getNumberOfNames() == 0){
            EntireName = " ";
        }else if(getNumberOfNames() == 1){
            EntireName = getFirstName();
        }else if(getNumberOfNames() == 2){
            EntireName = getFirstName() + " " + getMiddleName();
        }else if(getNumberOfNames() == 3){
            EntireName = getFirstName() + " " + getMiddleName() + " " + getLastName();
        }else {
            EntireName = getFirstName() + " " + getMiddleName() + " " + getLastName() + " " + getSuffixName();
        }
        return EntireName;
    }
    public String Initials(){
        String f = getFirstName(); 
        char fChar = f.charAt(0);

        String m = getMiddleName();
        char mChar = m.charAt(0);

        String l = getLastName();
        char lChar = l.charAt(0);

        String s = getSuffixName();
        char sChar = s.charAt(0);

        String initial = " ";

          if(getNumberOfNames() == 0){
            initial = " ";
        }else if(getNumberOfNames() == 1){
            initial = fChar + ".";
        }else if(getNumberOfNames() == 2){
            initial = fChar + "." + mChar + ".";
        }else if(getNumberOfNames() == 3){
            initial = fChar + "." + mChar + "." + lChar + ".";
        }

        //String initial = fChar + "." +  mChar + "." + lChar ;
       return initial; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the line that throws the Exception? Have you even tried to debug yourself?

Comment: I've been working on this for hours, so yes I've tried debugging. I have a tester program that returns the error java.lang.StringIndexoutofboundexception: String index out of Range: 0  at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)   at PersonName.Initials(PersonName.java:131)    atTestPersonName2.testOneName(TestPersonName2.java:50)

Comment: post the code that causes the error, as well as the error message, in order that we may help you find the cause.

Comment: Usually giving us a stacktrace helps us debug it

Comment: So which is the line that throws the Exception? Anyway, my guess is that you got an empty string or length 0 array somewhere, and you access the index 0 of the string or array.

Comment: A couple of good coding practices:
1. Do not use the format firstName for variables. They are generally left to functions. Instead use "_"
2. For the if condition "if((f.length() == 0) && (firstName.length() == 0)){
          numberOfNames = numberOfNames;   
        }", prefer not to use the curly brackets, that is use just "if((f.length() == 0) && (firstName.length() == 0)); //nothing done.."

Comment: @ManasPaldhe - I disagree.  On both counts.  It's perfectly OK, by most coding standards, to use leading lower case for variable names.  And it's generally a bad idea to avoid the `{}` for an `if` clause -- too often you end up coming back and adding another statement to the clause, and it erroneously ends up in the "mainline".

Comment: @HotLicks: The first suggestion, I was asked to follow during summer intern at software company. You may be right though.
About the second, I think I wrote it imperfectly. I should have said to avoid unnecessary if conditions.
Thanks for pointing.

Comment: I've got 40 years in the biz.  There are a few shops that prefer the leading "_", but most don't, or reserve that form for specific cases.  Just keeping leading upper (for class names) and leading lower (for variables/methods) separate is the important thing, as that's a fairly universal (except for Microsoft) standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the function, firstname is empty;
Now in the function, the statement

```
  String f = getFirstName(); 
  char fChar = f.charAt(0);
```

is executed.
Since f is empty (firstName =""; has been done initially) the fChar gives that exception.

Update it to:

```
    String s = getSuffixName();
    char sChar = s.charAt(0);

    String initial = " ";

      if(getNumberOfNames() == 0){
        initial = " ";
    }else if(getNumberOfNames() == 1){
        String f = getFirstName(); 
        char fChar = f.charAt(0);
        initial = fChar + ".";
    }else if(getNumberOfNames() == 2){
         String f = getFirstName(); 
         char fChar = f.charAt(0);
         String m = getMiddleName();
         char mChar = m.charAt(0);
         initial = fChar + "." + mChar + ".";
    }else if(getNumberOfNames() == 3){
         String f = getFirstName(); 
         char fChar = f.charAt(0);
         String m = getMiddleName();
         char mChar = m.charAt(0);
         String l = getLastName();
         char lChar = l.charAt(0);
        initial = fChar + "." + mChar + "." + lChar + ".";
    }
```

**Comment:**

Note that in the code, if getNumberOfNames() == 1, you are assuming that it is the firstname. Ensure that this is always valid. If not then you will get an error.

Comment: `When you call the function, firstname is null;` Most likely this is NOT the case. You will get NullPointerException rather than an IndexOuttOfBoundsException if you dereference `null`. `firstname` is already initialized to empty string in the constructor, and setting first name to `null` will cause a `NullPointerException` in `setFirstName`. The error is due to `charAt(0)` being called on the empty string.

Comment: I agree! Good point. However note that firstname is initialized as firstName="";  So it is zero sized string. Therefore here it is  IndexOuttOfBoundsException and not NullPointerException.
If it was not initialized or was initialized as null, I would expect NullPOinterException.

Answer (score 0):

Manas beat me to it.
However, I would also check your set methods (ie. setFirstName())

```
public void setFirstName(String f){
    if((f.length() == 0) && (firstName.length() == 0)){
      numberOfNames = numberOfNames;   
    }else if(( f.length() > 0) && (firstName.length() == 0)){
        numberOfNames++;
    }
    firstName = f; // FIRST NAME IS SET OUTSIDE OF CONDITION, WHETHER f.length() == 0 OR NOT
}
```

Also, your numberOfNames counter is flawed. If only the middle name is set, the counter will increment by 1 but, will return firstName instead of middle.
Try to rethink the logic and refactor the code

good luck :)